# Using C# Console.Write* with AWS Lambda

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, lambda

I feel like an idiot for asking such a basic question but here goes... I'm trying out AWS Lambda in C# for the first time and according to the docs:

> Anything written to standard out or standard error - using
>   Console.Write or a similar method - will be logged in CloudWatch Logs.

OK well upon execution I get the following runtime exception:

```
Unable to load DLL 'api-ms-win-core-processenvironment-l1-1-0.dll': The specified module could not be found.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E): DllNotFoundException
at Interop.mincore.GetStdHandle(Int32 nStdHandle)
at System.ConsolePal.GetStandardFile(Int32 handleType, FileAccess access)
at System.Console.<>c.<get_Out>b__25_0()
at System.Console.EnsureInitialized[T](T& field, Func`1 initializer)
at System.Console.WriteLine(String value)
```

My question is, how / where am I supposed to add the reference it's asking for? The answer seems non obvious.

Comment: One thing to note about using `Console.WriteLine()` is that it is slow, and sometimes the messages will appear out of order in cloudwatch (e.g. the REPORT line will come before your last log line). Just FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well turns out in the project.json file under the dependencies node, the wizard's serverless template made a reference to Microsoft.NETCore.App without specifying a "type" of "platform". I spotted other samples online where the type line was present and once I added it, everything started working!

```
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "type": "platform",
        "version": "1.1.0"
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to `Console.Write` or `Console.WriteLine`, you can use the `Log` method on the static `Amazon.Lambda.Core.LambdaLogger` class.

```
private void DoSomething() {
    LambdaLogger.Log("Log message");
}
```

Some more info can be found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dotnet-logging.html